# Can make a Search with a template form work

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms

I use crispy-forms in all of my search,but in this one I need to do it with a template form, I don't know what's wrong with my code 'cause I have the same code in other project and it works fine, I don't know if is the Django version, currently I'm using 1.8. The error that I get is Page not found (404), I doesn't find the url.Here's my code hope you can help me. I use q and param in the url but none works.

urls.py

```
url(r'^search/(?P<param>\S+)$', permission_required('agenda.change_agenda', login_url='/no_access')(SearchContact.as_view()), name='searchcontact'),
```

template_form.html

```
<form class="well form-search" action="/search/" method="get">
  <input type="text" class="input-medium search-query" name="param">
  <button type="submit" class="btn">Search</button>
</form>
```

views.py

```
class SearchContact(ListView):
    template_name = 'agenda_contacts.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        query = self.request.GET.get('param')
        return Agenda.objects.filter(name=param)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex

```
r'^search/(?P<param>\S+)$
```

matches urls like `/search/hello` or `/search/my-search`.

However, your search form is sending the search terms in the `GET` paramters, for example `/search/?param=hello` or `/search/?param=my-search`.

GET parameters are not captured in urls.py. You can access them with `request.GET` in the view as you are already doing.

Therefore, you should remove `param` from the regex, and change your url pattern to the following.

```
url(r'^search/$', permission_required('agenda.change_agenda', login_url='/no_access')(SearchContact.as_view()), name='searchcontact'),
```

Comment: Thanks, That made it, it Works now.